# Add a color schema

Tags: ckan

I´m trying to add another color schema to the default schemas in Ckan 2.2

Follow the documentation, i run the next steps:

1. Activate the enviroment

   . /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate
2. Go to the ckans folder

   cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan
3. Run the command to generate color schema

   paster color "#0066aa"

   Here the console write:

   ```
    0.5 0.9
    @layoutLinkColor: #067979;
    @mastheadBackgroundColor: #089f9f;
    @btnPrimaryBackground: #0ac6c6;
    @btnPrimaryBackgroundHighlight: #0ceded;

    Color scheme has been created.
    Make sure less is run for changes to take effect.
   ```
4. Now I run the command to regenerate css files

   paster less

   And here console says:

   ```
   compile green.css
   compile fuchsia.css
   compile maroon.css
   compile red.css
   compile main.css
   ```

But the schema with the new colors doesn´t appears in the administrator web. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: No, is another problem. The new css doesn´t appears in the file system.